# Log Websites Visited With DDWRT

Tags: logging, dd-wrt

I have a netgear wndr4300 and have flashed ddwrt to it.  Is it possible for me to do websites visited & by what computer name logging on this set-up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this HowToGeek article:
http://www.howtogeek.com/68886/how-to-configure-your-router-for-network-wide-url-logging/

The article offers several solutions:
1. Global logging without the granularity of logging hostnames that requested a site
2. Detailed logging using OpenDNS that includes the hostnames of the requesting machines, but will induce a 12-24 hour lag in the logging before they become available to you
3. The more difficult but best fitting for your question solution:  setting up local logging on your router and utilizing [WallWatcher](http://www.wallwatcher.com/)  software to parse the logs into something more human-readable.

Their router had the Tomato firmware installed, but ddwrt should be able to handle this just fine with a little searching around the settings menus.

Best of luck,
-Ryan